# Back-propagation in Convolution layer

Tags: conv-neural-network, backpropagation

Most examples I found on the internet explain well back-propagation in convolution layer, but only with a single kernel and single input channel.

I do not understand how to do back-propagation for more than one kernel and more than one input channel.

Let's say I have a convolution layer which accepts an input $X$ of size **3x20x20**, applies **5** **3x3x3** kernel filters $K$ and produces an output $O$ of a size **5x18x18**

On a diagram it looks like that (I apologize for my horrible hand-drawing):
[image: Forward Pass]

During the backward pass the layer receives an error $\frac{\partial E}{\partial O}$ and propagates it back to the previous layer.

As I understand, in order to compute $\frac{\partial O}{\partial X}$ I need to apply *'full'* convolution to $\frac{\partial E}{\partial O}$ with a kernels rotated 180°. So, it looks like this:

[image: Backward Pass]

The dimensions of $\frac{\partial O}{\partial X}$ should match the dimensions of $X$ (3x20x20), but convolution operation produces an output with a depth equals to the number of kernels (in my case **5**).

My question is how a 'full' convolution between $\frac{\partial E}{\partial O}$ **5x18x18** over 5 rotated filters 3x3x3 can produce an output $\frac{\partial O}{\partial X}$ with dimension **3x20x20** ? Is not it that the depth of the output of convolution operation equals to the number of filters ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I try to explain the dimensions obtained (**5x18x18 -> 3x20x20**):

- **5 -> 3** the flipped convolutions are repeated 3 times, but the effects of each of the 5 filter are summed up, exactly as you do in the forward phase. In any case in a convolutional layer it is possible to give any depth in input and any number of filters in output as well.
  [image]
- **18 -> 20** is given by the full convolution, in which is applied a padding to the input image obtaining then a bigger image as result.

Anyway [here](https://medium.com/@pavisj/convolutions-and-backpropagations-46026a8f5d2c) the backpropagation in convolution layers is very well explained.

Comment: Could you summarize the link in your answer? Link-only answers are deprecated as links can die over time, making this answer less useful to future visitors.

Comment: I wrote that the link explains backpropagation for convolutional layers. Anyway it is not the main part of the answer, which is below.

Comment: @Tonka, I appreciate for your effort to explain it, but I still do not get it. I can only do convolution between two volumes of equal depth. Whether kernels rotated 180° or not, does not change its depth. During the backward pass $dE/dO$ I receive from previous layer has a dimension of 5x18x18, but kernels has dimension 3x3x3. Depth of kernel do not match the depth of $dE/dO$. Regarding the link you have provided, it covers case with a single kernel and single input channel and unfortunately does not answer my question.

Comment: Remember that convolution is only a 2-dimensional operation. You can try to visualize the whole set of filters as a matrix 3x5 and the convolution as a product. If you're propagating backwards then you need to transpose the matrix and you'll get the dimensions you seek.

Comment: @Tonca, Are you saying that in order to compute $\frac{\partial E}{\partial X}$ I need not only to rotate kernels 180°, but also transpose kernel depth and with kernel number i.e. 5 kernels with depth 3 would become 3 kernels with depth 5 ?

Comment: I've updated the answer.