# Convolution Backpropagation

Tags: conv-neural-network, backpropagation

My question is related to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/361817/347966) question answered here. I want to find $\frac {\partial E}{\partial K}$. For this I do convolution between $\frac {\partial E}{\partial O}$ and $X$.

I couldn't find anywhere for multiple channels and kernels. But intuitively, I propose the following:

convolve a 2D 18x18 dE/dO with 2D 20x20 input. Convolution of first 18x18 with 3 channels of input gives first 3x3 filter.
Similarly with other 4 channels of dE/dO to get 4 dE/dK.

I want to know if this is correct. Any confirmation/comments are appreciated!